# concat operator in wrkqry in as400

Tags: ibm-midrange

Using WRKQRY , I have to find the rows which have a tab character in a text field, for example in STRSQL, i normally use

```
select * from library/table where  
 table.field name LIKE '%' CONCAT CHR(9) CONCAT '%'
```

which is working fine. How can i use the similar query

```
table.field LIKE '%' CONCAT CHR(9) CONCAT '%'
```

in WRKQRY options? In record select in value field i have to use

```
'%' CONCAT CHR(9) CONCAT '%'
```

Comment: corrected markdown. Please make sure that this is still what you want to ask because the question is quite hard to read.

Answer (score 3):

`||` is the `WRKQRY` version of `CONCAT`

[image]

Consider changing your Query/400 query to an SQL based Query Manager (QM) query using the Retrieve Query Mgmt Query (RTVQMQRY) command with `ALWQRYDFN(*YES)`

Query Manager has a prompted mode very similar to Query/400.  But it also allows straight SQL.

Alternatively, you could look at the SQL based web-query product.  That's IBM's preferred upgrade from WRKQRY.

Lastly, you could build an SQL view with the concatenated column and use that in WRKQRY.

Comment: Haven't used Web Query, but you really can't do what you want with Query/400 unless you use a SQL view as the table. While you can build a variable with a tab and two wildcards `%` like you want, the LIKE operator in the record selection page requires a literal pattern, and you can't concatenate the pattern together.